# How can the verb integrate be used?

Tags: word-usage

Several issues here.

Can *integrate* be used...

A) in the passive when used in combination with immigrants? e.g. In the following sentence:
*immigrants should be integrated into society.*

B) as a reflexive verb?
E.g. In the following sentence:
*The immigrants from India integrated themselves well.*

C) as a transitive verb? E.g. In the following sentence:
*Government policy should aim at integrating immigrants into society.*

Comment: In most of these cases, I would prefer the more specific verb *assimilate*, but there's really nothing wrong with any of your examples as they are.

Comment: I was very unsure about the reflexive form. What you say is interesting as I would treat assimilate as a totally different verb with a totally different meaning (sort of melting pot / salad bowl thing)

Comment: Yeah, the melting pot idea is the one most typically aimed at in this context. The reflexive form is fine, though not common.

Answer (score 3):

The *verb* "to integrate" is used both with and without *object.* It doesn't have a *reflexive construction*.

"(The) Immigrants from India integrated well." is fine. Here, to integrate = to become integrated. 
"to integrate into" is common as well.

Another example, similar to yours:
"Many immigrants have found it difficult to integrate into American culture."

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/integrate